# Replacing loaded.bs.modal in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Why was the `loaded.bs.modal` event removed from Bootstrap 4? Is there anything that can replace it? `shown.bs.modal` is quite similar but it doesn't wait for the modal to be fully loaded, only to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to open the modal manually and implement the Ajax loading yourself. Something like:

```
 $modal.modal({
    'show': true
   }).load('request_url', function (e) {
     // this is executed when the content has loaded.
 });
```

an other option is to append a hidden object as th last in the modal body and check for that to appear in DOM.

As another solution you could add a timeout to either show.bs OR shown.bs (big difference)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       //Do something if necessary
   }, 300);   //add what is appropriate                     
})
```

Which solution is the best depends on your use case.

Comment: I'll try the first approach, since I'm already using the second one. Thanks!